# Image isn't opening in expand mode in IE only

Tags: html, css, image, expand, expander

[Check out the picture please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsnpb.png)
Expand mode or maximize button is disabled and this is only happening in IE. Any recommendation on how to fix it? Below is my coding, am I doing anything wrong?

```
sendImageDocsToHTML(imageDocuments) {
    var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outerDiv.setAttribute("id","dtleImagesDiv");
    outerDiv.setAttribute("class","dtle");
    for(var x=0; x< imageDocuments.length; x++){
        var ele = document.createElement("img");
        ele.setAttribute("class", "image img-responsive");
        ele.setAttribute("src", imageDocuments[x].imageFullURL);
        outerDiv.appendChild(ele);
        outerDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
    var divContent = outerDiv.outerHTML;
    var myWindow = this.nativeWindow.open('','','width=auto,height=1000px');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    this.translateService.get('document_images_window_header').subscribe(value => {
        doc.write('<html><head><title>' + value + '</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link href="../assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/lotdisplay.css"></head><body><div class="container"><div class="col-sm-12 text-center">');
        doc.write(divContent);
        doc.write('</div></div></body></html>');
        doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you tested with multiple images, several of which work, suggests it's less likely about the code. See if it's something wrong with that second image URL. IE has developer tools. See if you can get any diagnostic information from its attempt to show the image.

Browsers have different capabilities for decoding various image formats. For example, WebP https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp is currently supported in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome, while not supported in IE.